# Problems with field validation script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code that reads:

```
$(this).keyup(function () {
  if(regex.test(this.value))
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.validColor;
else
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.invalidColor;
});
```

This is supposed to provide a visual cue to the user, about the field he or she is typing in, however, this just flips the colour on every keypress.

Comment: And when should it be triggered? This depends heavily on how your regex looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function for the [keyup event](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) should be take an [eventObject parameter](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).  This exposes a [which property](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) that provides [information about the keycode/character code that was pressed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes).

You should pass that to your test to see if a keypress is valid/invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what response the `test` function returns, you can try like this:

```
$(this).keyup(function () {
  if(!regex.test(this.value))
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.invalidColor;
else
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.validColor;        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it heavily depends on the regex you are matching.

You should try to debug it first:

(I will be continuing with Sarfraz's code).

```
$(this).keyup(function () {
  if(!regex.test(this.value))
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.invalidColor;
    $('#debug').html('invalid color');
else
    this.style.backgroundColor=config.validColor;        
    $('#debug').html('valid color!');
});
```

Also, since you are using jQuery, you should rely more on its 'write less' philosophy.

```
$(this).keyup(function () {
  if(!regex.test(this.value))
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', config.invalidColor);
    $('#debug').html('invalid color');
else
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', config.validColor);
});
```

Maybe you should paste the regular expression code and what you are trying to achieve.